# Change of Coordinates and Basis

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, change-of-basis

Let $P_{2}(\mathbb{R})$ denote the vector space of real polynomial functions of degree less than or
equal to two and let $\beta := \{p_{0}, p_{1}, p_{2}\}$ denote the natural basis of $P_{2}(\mathbb{R}) $  so $p_{i}(x) = x_{
i}$
).

Define $g ∈ P_{2}(\mathbb{R})$ by $g(x) = 3 + 4x − x^{
2}$

Write g as a linear combination of the elements of
B. Compute the coordinate vector $g_{\beta}$ of g with respect to $\beta$.

Define $h_{1}, h_{2}, h_{3} ∈ P_{2}(\mathbb{R})$ by $h_{1}(x) = −2, h_{2}(x) = 4 − x$ and $h_{3}(x) = 6 + x^{
2}$
,

and let
$C := \{h_{1}, h_{2}, h_{3}\}$ be another basis of $P_{2}(\mathbb{R})$. Construct the change of coordinate matrix A
from C to $\beta$. Compute $A^{
−1}$
. Compute the coordinate vector $g_{C}$ of g with respect to C.

I have this question for revision for exam but am not sure how to start this is $$g_{\beta} = \begin{matrix}
  1 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 4 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & -1
 \end{matrix} $$

or is $$g_{\beta} = \begin{matrix}
  1 \\
  4   \\
  -1 
 \end{matrix} $$

Any help would be appreciated thank you.